# Problem in using org.apache.ddlutils.DdlUtilsException

Tags: java, metadata, ddlutils

I'm trying to use the **org.apache.ddlutils** package for reading database metadata.
I've written the following method:

```
public static void readMetaData(DataSource dataSource) throws DdlUtilsException{

    final Platform platform = PlatformFactory.createNewPlatformInstance(dataSource);
}
```

But the statement ***throws DdlUtilsException*** gives the following error:

*No exception of type DdlUtilsException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable*

I simply do not understand the reason behind this error because the API at http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/api/org/apache/ddlutils/DdlUtilsException.html clearly states the following:

```
java.lang.Object
  extended by java.lang.Throwable
      extended by java.lang.Exception
          extended by java.lang.RuntimeException
              extended by org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException
                  extended by org.apache.ddlutils.DdlUtilsException
```

Please advice.

Comment: Just for later reference. Apache DdlUtils 1.0 depends on Apache Commons Lang 2.6. Later versions (3.0+) are not compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you've got another class called `DdlUtilsException` somewhere - possibly in the top-level package, given that the compiler isn't mentioning a full package name. If you're using Eclipse or something similar, try to navigate to the class declaration.

EDIT: Okay, judging by your comment, you aren't including the various dependencies. Make sure you've downloaded DdlUtils-1.0-bin.zip, and the dependencies are all in the lib directory. It's not immediately clear to me whether you need *all* of them, but you might as well use them all to start with, and then remove what you don't need.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the reply!! I've only used the jar DdlUtils-1.0.jar in the build path. There is no other jar file. But when I look in the errors view of eclipse, it says "The type org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" What could be the reason for this error???

Comment: @n_g: Sounds like the compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong. You need to add some dependencies, including apache.commons. The ddlutils home page should tell you want dependencies you need.

Comment: I've just looked at the DdlUtils 1.0 release, and the zip file contains various dependencies.

Comment: @n_g: But if you haven't added the other dependencies, you're likely to have a problem elsewhere... at execution time rather than compile-time maybe, but still a problem...

Comment: @Jon: You are right. But right now even I'm not sure about what other dependencies I'll need :) ... So I'll add other jars as I progress with my development.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that other class 'org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException' is located in commons-lang. Download and add that jar and it should work. Check the docs for DDL Utils and see what else it depends on.